# My googlesearch is not working in multiprocess pool, it gives a MaybeEncodingError

Tags: python, multiprocessing, google-search

Currently I'm trying to use multiple processing to search up book titles find their first 30 summary links with googlesearch on python

```
from googlesearch import search
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool
import json
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlparse

SAVE_PDF_PATH = "../books_pdf"
SAVE_SUM_PATH = "../summary_txt"
def perform_search(title):
    """Perform search for the title summaries and save it's texts into files
    return quadruples of (url, domain, starting depth = 0 , maxdepth) used for crawl"""
    
    dir_path =f"{SAVE_SUM_PATH}/{title}"
    #print(f"dir_path: {dir_path}")
    try:
        os.mkdir(dir_path) #create a directory if needed
    except:
        pass
    query = title + " summary"
    print(f"query: {query}")
    results = list()
    for url in search(query, num = 30, stop = 30, verify_ssl = False):
        results.append(url)
    return results
def main():
    
    titles = list()
    for title in os.listdir(SAVE_PDF_PATH):
        titles.append(title[:-4])
    
    search_stuff = titles[0:2]
    print(f"search_stuff: {search_stuff}")
    p = Pool()
    results = p.map(perform_search, titles[0:2])
    p.close()
    p.join()
    
    # p2 = Pool()
    # results = p2.map(crawl, quads)
    # p2.close()
    # p2.join()
    print(f"results: {results}")
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The thing is it worked at one point then stopped working, if I comment out the search then the multiprocessing works again.
Otherwise it gives me this error:

```
  File "/Users/yao/Desktop/dkp/School/projects/Stuff_with_Books/summary_scraper/sum_scrape.py", line 73, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/yao/Desktop/dkp/School/projects/Stuff_with_Books/summary_scraper/sum_scrape.py", line 62, in main
    results = p.map(perform_search, titles[0:2])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 364, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '<multiprocessing.pool.ExceptionWithTraceback object at 0x7fa4750c4490>'. Reason: 'TypeError("cannot pickle '_io.BufferedReader' object")'
```

Comment: It is against Google's [Webmaster Guidelines](//developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/webmaster-guidelines) and [terms of service](//policies.google.com/terms/archive/20020906?hl=en) to submit programmatic search queries. Running this code against Google is likely to cause Google to show captcha for searches from your IP address.

Comment: Is there a way I can get search queries fast without getting blocked?

Comment: Build your own search engine rather than using Google.